# Can not Insert the NULL value into Auto Increment PrimaryKey Column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, primary-key

I have created the table `Items` in C# database as the property of the primary key is AutoIncrement=True, AutoIncrementStep=1, Unique=True, AutoIncrementSeeds=0;

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Items] 
(
    [item_id]       INT          NOT NULL,
    [item_name]     VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [item_model]    VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [item_price]    VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [item_quantity] VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [entry_date]    VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [user_id]       VARCHAR (50) NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([item_id] ASC)
);
```

and I am inserting data into the `Items` table using this code:

```
string query = @"Insert into Items(item_name, item_model, item_price, item_quantity, entry_date, user_id)" +
                "VALUES(@name, @model, @price, @quantity, @date, @user)";

using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.Database1ConnectionString))
{
    try
    {
        c.Open();

        if (c.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(query, c);

            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name.Text.ToString());
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@model", model.Text.ToString());
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", price.Text.ToString());
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", quantity.Text.ToString());
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", dateTimePicker1.Text.ToString());
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", added_by.Text.ToString());

            int k = command1.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (k > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Data Added Successfully");
                c.Close();
                return;
            }
            else 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Data was not added successfully - try again later");
                c.Close();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Failed To Open Connection :." + ex);
        return;
    }
}
```

When I run code and try to insert data I get error

> Cannot Insert NULL value into column 'item_id' table

Comment: @Dan Guzman - SQL Server MVP I hope you can help :)

Comment: I am curious to know how do you have determined that AutoIncrement is true. (By the way it is called IDENTITY in SqlServer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NOT NULL` means you can't insert `NULL` into those columns you need to explicitly insert it.

Setting `IDENTITY(1,1)` will insert `item_id` automatically by seed of 1.

Change your definition like this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Items] (
[item_id]       INT          NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
[item_name]     VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[item_model]    VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[item_price]    VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[item_quantity] VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[entry_date]    VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[user_id]       VARCHAR (50) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([item_id] ASC)
);
```

OR

explicitly insert it into database

```
string query = @"Insert into Items(item_id,item_name,item_model,item_price,item_quantity,entry_date,user_id)" +
                "VALUES(@item_id,@name, @model, @price, @quantity, @date,@user)";
```

Stop using `.AddWithValues`
[Source](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: one thing more it add data successfully but when i close the C# app than all the data which i save in the database it gone mean databse is empty i also check the data by Right Click on table and than click on show the data the table is empty

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar can you explain why you say stop using `.AddWithValue`? Thanks.

Comment: @andrew.cuthbert Source Added in the Answer